# Session cookie issue in IE8 for Classic ASP code running on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7)

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, internet-explorer-8, session-state, session-variables

I needed to run a development server for our Classic ASP intranet application on a Windows 7 machine at home, and managed to install it with no problems, except that session data does not seem to store on IE8 browsers, but works fine on other browsers.

If I write a simple script just to see the session ID and see what happens when I refresh the page, I get an incrementing ID in IE, but a fixed ID in all other browsers.

```
<%
response.write "SessionID : " & session.sessionID & "<br />"
%>
```

I've got privacy settings set to accept all cookies in IE, but to no avail.  I've used CCcleaner to clear all IE settings and done a reset in IE, but that hasn't helped either.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an app pool problem.
 See this stackflow post [IIS7 and Classic ASP Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785446/iis7-and-classic-asp-sessions)